# Can't access form elements with onload() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, field, onload

I'm putting together dependent drop-downs (Teacher -> Class -> Student) and am having issues with setting the initial state of the drop-downs.  Here's the code:

**edit_contract.html**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}    
<div>
    <form method="post" id="contractForm" novalidate 
        data-teachers-url="{% url 'wakemeup:ajax_load_teachers' %}" 
        data-classes-url="{% url 'wakemeup:ajax_load_classes' %}" 
        data-students-url="{% url 'wakemeup:ajax_load_students' %}" 
    >
        {% crispy form %}
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    // Update class drop-down when teacher changes
    $("#id_teacheruserid").change(function () {
        update_classes($(this))
      });

    // Update students drop-down when class changes
    $("#id_classid").change(function () {
        update_students($(this))
      });

    function update_teachers() {
        // Get form values
        var url = $("#contractForm").attr("data-teachers-url");
        var contractId = $(document.getElementById("id_contractid")).val();

        $.ajax({                             // initialize AJAX request
          url: url,                         
          data: {
            'contractid': contractId
          },
          success: function (data) {            
            $("#id_teacheruserid").html(data);  // Update "teacheruserid" field
          }
        })

        update_classes(); // Update classes drop-down
    };

    function update_classes() {
        // Get form values
        var url = $("#contractForm").attr("data-classes-url");
        var teacherUserId = $(document.getElementById("id_teacheruserid")).val();
        var contractId = $(document.getElementById("id_contractid")).val();

        $.ajax({                            // initialize AJAX request
          url: url,                         
          data: {
            'teacheruserid': teacherUserId, 
            'contractid': contractId
          },
          success: function (data) {        
            $("#id_classid").html(data);       // Update "classid" field
          }
        })

        update_students(); // Update students drop-down
    };

    function update_students() {
        // Get form values
        var url = $("#contractForm").attr("data-students-url");
        var classId = $(document.getElementById("id_classid")).val();
        var contractId = $(document.getElementById("id_contractid")).val();

        $.ajax({                                // initialize AJAX request
          url: url,                                 
          data: {
            'classid': classId,                     
            'contractid': contractId
          },
          success: function (data) {                
            $("#id_partyuserinfo").html(data);      // Update "partyuserinfo" field
          }
        })
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        // Initial load of drop-down menus
        update_teachers(); // Cascades to update_classes() and update_students()
    };      
</script>
```

### Flow summary

*update_teacher()*
- update HTML (drop-down options) for "id_teacheruserid" field

*update_classes()*
- read value from "id_teacheruserid" field (undefined for initial load)
- update HTML (drop-down options) for "id_classid" field

*update_students()*
- read value from "id_classid" field (undefined for initial load)
- update HTML (drop-down options) for "id_partyuserinfo" field

### The problem

The problem I'm seeing is that the script can't access the values in the form fields in the `onload()` call.  For example, this line in `update_classes()`:

```
    var teacherUserId = $(document.getElementById("id_teacheruserid")).val();
```

I added an `alert(teacherUserId)` directly after this line.  On initial page load, it returns `undefined`.  However, when I select a different value from the teacher drop-down, the alert displays the expected value.

My guess is that in the initial `onload()`, the referenced field values/options (i.e. `id_teacheruserid`) have not been loaded or made available yet.  The fields themselves exist, but return `undefined` values.  Once this function completes, though,  it seems they are then accessible and the menus behave as expected.

How can I run `update_teachers()` to do the initial load and have it access the form field values?

Comment: You are calling your functions before the ajax has finished (ie they aren't called in the success callback)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22519785/2813224

Comment: You're right, thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can use

```
$("#id_teacheruserid").val();
```

instead of

```
$(document.getElementById("id_teacheruserid"))
```

Second

you need to grab the option selected value from the dropdown

```
$("#id_teacheruserid").find(":selected").val()
```

to get the selected ID

Third, you need to call next drop down fill function on success callback

```
$.ajax({                             // initialize AJAX request
          url: url,                         
          data: {
            'contractid': contractId
          },
          success: function (data) {            
            $("#id_teacheruserid").html(data);  // Update "teacheruserid" field
             update_classes();
          }
        })
```

Comment: You don't need to select the actual `<option>` element. `<select>` elements have a `value` property

Comment: i guess this is and old habit from almost never using a non masked select tag, but you are totally right @PatrickEvans

Comment: You guys are right!  Thanks so much for your quick help, I appreciate it.

Comment: This is my first time delving into AJAX/JQuery.  Is the code I've written above compatible across most platforms / devices?  Are there any gotchas I need to worry about?

Comment: @ravioli you are ok, jQuery has pretty good browser compatibility, please DO NOT leave any console.log on IE :D